# Передать данные из одного фрагмента в другой

Tags: android

Есть PlayerActivity, в котором через ViewPager созданы два фрагмента.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    ***

    setupViewPager();
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment1.newInstance(id, songTitle, songImg, songFile, songAuthor, songText),"Плеер");
    adapter.addFragment(Fragment2.newInstance(id, songText),"Текст песни");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    DotsIndicator dotsIndicator = (DotsIndicator) findViewById(R.id.dots_indicator);
    dotsIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Второй фрагмент выглядит так

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    long id;
    String songText;

    private TextView txtSongText;

    public static Fragment2 newInstance(long id, String songText) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong("ID", id);
        args.putString("songText", songText);

        Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        fragment2.setArguments(args);
        return fragment2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        txtSongText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtSongText);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        id = getArguments().getLong("ID");
        songText = getArguments().getString("songText");
    }
}
```

Первый также, но количество параметров другое. Теперь в методе selectData() первого фрагмента пытаюсь передать данные во второй фрагмент таким образом, но ничего не получается

```
private void selectData(String query) {
    ***
    try {
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                ***

                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("songText", songText);

                Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
                fragment2.setArguments(args);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как передать данные из фрагмента1 в фрагмент2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте интерфейс в `FragmentOne`:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

//Объявление интерфейса
OnDataSelectListener onDataSelectListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    Button btnPassData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPassData);
    btnPassData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           onDataSelectListener.onSelectData("Привет от Первого Фрагмента!!!");
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

//Ваш интерфейс
public interface OnDataSelectListener{
    void onSelectData(String data);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        onDataSelectListener = (OnDataSelectListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Error in retrieving data. Please try again");
    }
    }
}
```

`Fragment`, который принимает данные:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    TextView txtData;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        txtData = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtData);
        return rootView;
    }

    protected void displayReceivedData(String message) {
        txtData.setText("Data received: " + message);
    }
}
```

`Activity` реализовывает `FragmentOne` и отправляет данные к `FragmentTwo`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentOne.OnDataSelectListener{

    @Override
    public void onSelectData(String data) {
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1;
        FragmentTwo f = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        f.displayReceivedData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Мало что понял. А можно пояснить что происходит в методе onViewCreated первого фрагмента и что за метод displayReceivedData во втором фрагменте?

Comment: И неужели нельзя в моем случае через Bundle как-то передать данные во второй фрагмент из первого?

Comment: Может быть в интерфейсе метод тоже должен называться sendData?

Comment: Изменил ответ! Метод `displayReceivedData()`, назовите его как хотите, просто он объявлен во втором фрагменте, и ему отправляет данные активити в методе `onSelectData(String data)`

Comment: Ошибку выбрасывает в строке f.displayReceivedData(message); Activity   Fragment2.displayReceivedData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `findFragmentByTag("Текст песни");`

Comment: А как его узнать? У меня не используется компонент fragment. Созданы два layout для каждого фрагмента

Comment: Попробуйте вместо findFragmentByTag("Текст песни");  так и пробовал

Comment: Попробуйте использовать латиницу без пробелов вместо кирилицы

Comment: Прописал в методе setupViewPager так adapter.addFragment(Fragment2.newInstance(id, songText),"SongText");, а в методе onSelectData так Fragment2 f = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SongText");. Все равно ошибка

Comment: Обновил ответ. Попробуйте!!!

Comment: Получилось! А что происходит в этой строчке поясните пожалуйста String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1;

Comment: Просто в viewPager адаптере 2 фрагмента, соответственно тэг по умолчанию первого - 0, второго - 1

Comment: Понял, спасибо.